# ASP.NET Razor Form Data not being passed to variables used in e-mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email, razor

I'm just now experimenting with ASP.NET and Razor, I'm trying to take a simple HTML form and have it pass data to Variables on POST and use those variables to build a simple e-mail sent by SMTP. However it appears that the data is not being passed to these variables as when the e-mail is sent they are blank. If I hard-code values to these variables they get shown correctly. Here is a snippet of the code I'm working with. Ignore the localhost under WebMail.SmtpServer, I'm using SMTP4dev to test the e-mail functionality locally. This first section is the razor code:

```
@{
var errorMessage = "";

if (IsPost)
{

    var fromEmail = "user@localhost";
    var body = Request["requestDate"];
    var requestorName = Request["requestorName"];
    var subject = requestorName;//( "IT Account Request for "+ @requestorName +" ." );

    try {
        WebMail.SmtpServer = "localhost";
        WebMail.SmtpPort = 25;
        WebMail.EnableSsl = false;
        WebMail.UserName = "user@localhost";
        WebMail.Password = "smtppassword";
        WebMail.From = fromEmail;
        WebMail.Send(to: "test@localhost",
            subject: subject,
            body: body




        );
    }
    catch (Exception ex ) {
        errorMessage = ex.Message;
    }
}
}
<div>Error: @errorMessage </div>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    <table id="requestor_information_form">
        <tr>
            <td class="top"><img src="images\logo.png"></img></td>
            <td class="top">Account Request</td>
            <td class="top" colspan ="2"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="tableHeading" colspan="4">Requestor Information</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Requestor:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="requestorName"></td>

            <td>Request Date:</td>
            <td><input type="date" name="requestDate"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Requestor Phone:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="requestorPhoneNum"></td>
                    </tr>
  </form>
```

Comment: First off, where does your form actually post to? (action=""). Second, I often find it better to use the Html-helpers when creating forms. @Html.BeginForm(). Just a tip :)

Comment: The form was initially posting to a second page which is where I attempted to do the e-mail sending, however I had some of the same issues there. I found an example floating around on google that placed the e-mail sending code into the same page as the form, and it worked, when I modified it for my purposes I ran into the issues I'm now experiencing. Thanks for the tip, clearly I'm not nearly as good as I sometimes think I am :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `enctype` from the form, or set it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is the default.

Answer (score 0):

The point of MVC really is separation of concerns. So having your SMTP code right in your view is definitely bad practice here.

What you really want to do is create a ViewModel which will represent your form fields being submitted:

```
public class EmailViewModel 
{
    public string RequestorName { get; set; }
    public string RequestorPhoneNum { get; set; }
    public DateTime RequestorDate { get; set; }
}
```

This way, we can manage form data in an object oriented way. Now your Controller should handle data passed to/from your views. So you'd want to build your controller something similar to:

```
public class EmailController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Email() 
    {
        var viewModel = new EmailViewModel();

        // Pass an empty view model to your view
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    // This controller action will be hit when you submit your form
    // and the default MVC model binder will create your viewModel with
    // the appropriate values submitted from your form.
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Email(EmailViewModel viewModel)
    {
        // Make sure the data coming server-side is valid
        // You can use validation attributes like [Required] in your View Model
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try 
            {
                WebMail.SmtpServer = "localhost";
                WebMail.SmtpPort = 25;
                WebMail.EnableSsl = false;
                WebMail.UserName = "user@localhost";
                WebMail.Password = "smtppassword";
                WebMail.From = "user@localhost";;
                WebMail.Send(
                    "test@localhost", 
                    viewModel.RequestorName, // RequestorName entered from form
                    viewModel.RequestorDate.ToString() // RequestorDate entered from form
                );
            }
            catch (Exception ex ) 
            {
                errorMessage = ex.Message;
            }
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

and now you'd want to strongly type your View, so that it can build your form fields for you:

```
@model EmailViewModel

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
<table id="requestor_information_form">
    <tr>
        <td class="top"><img src="images\logo.png"></img></td>
        <td class="top">Account Request</td>
        <td class="top" colspan ="2"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="tableHeading" colspan="4">Requestor Information</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.RequestorName)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.RequestorName)</td>

        <td>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.RequestorDate</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.RequestorDate)</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.RequestorPhoneNum)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.RequestorPhoneNum)</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Send Email" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

Again, the point of MVC is separation of concerns. So, your View's should strictly be the user interface with absolutely no business logic within them. Let the controller handle what to do with the data, and always use ViewModels to hold data being transferred to/from your views.

Comment: The code in the OP doesn't look like MVC. It looks like Razor Web Pages. I suspect that the MVC tag has been incorrectly applied.